# The type or namespace name 'IQueryable' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, build

I have a weird issue. I have a VS 2010 .Net 4.0 Web Site (not web app) that runs on IIS 7.5.
When I build the site, I'm getting errors like the one in the title.  Normally, this would be straightforward to fix - just add a reference.

In this case, I already have a reference to System.Core.Dll (4.0). I have "using System.Linq" declared.

If I fully quality my references to IQueryable (e.g. System.Linq.Iqueryable), autocomplete resolves it perfectly.

All my folders are read/write enabled.

I'm not sure what else to check.

Maybe one of my fellow Overflowers can help?  :-)

TIA!

Comment: Is the namespace included in the web.config? I recall some option like that for non-web apps.

Comment: is it running on an ASP.NET 4 application pool?

Comment: @leppie - I am referencing the assembly in the web.config:        
 <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>

thanks!

Comment: @onof - Yes, the app pool is .net 4.

Comment: Found it! I found the error...it seems that there was an error in an upstream web.config that was causing my build to fail.  I wish I knew why the symptoms manifested the way they did, but I'm building now.  :-)

Thanks to all who answered and tried to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error...it seems that there was an error in an upstream web.config that was causing my build to fail.  I wish I knew why the symptoms manifested the way they did, but I'm building now.  :-)

Thanks to all who answered and tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Target Framework is set to ".Net Framework 4" in the property pages